# Jenkins for Scala (SBT) Git master => Build => Test => Build Docker => Push into hub.docker

Tags: git, scala, docker

I want use continues delivery on Jenkins for stack:
Git
Scala (SBT)
Docker

Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo "Compiling..."
                sh "${tool name: 'sbt', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'}/bin/sbt compile"
            }
        }

        stage('Docker Publish') {
            steps {
                // Generate Jenkinsfile and prepare the artifact files.
                sh "${tool name: 'sbt', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'}/bin/sbt docker:stage"

                // Run the Docker tool to build the image
                script {
                    docker.withTool('docker') {
                        docker.build('my-app:latest', 'target/docker/stage')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I have next message on step "Docker Publish":

```
[job1] Running shell script

+ /var/jenkins_home/tools/org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder_SbtInstallation/sbt/bin/sbt docker:stage

[info] Set current project to job1 (in build file:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/job1/)

[error] Not a valid key: stage (similar: state, target, tags)

[error] docker:stage

[error]             ^

script returned exit code 1
```

I don't know this trouble reason.

Comment: Try `stage('DockerPublish') {` instead, without spaces

Comment: Changed to: `stage('DockerPublish') {` result the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in build.sbt file:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.JavaAppPackaging 
//enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging) 
enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging)
```

Add in project/plugin.sbt file:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.2.0")
```

Refresh SBT project.

It is in SBT version 0.13.16